# UISearchController presented as Popover in iPad is not visible

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm a little stumped with this.

```
        private void OnSearchButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var searchView = _appointmentSearchViewProvider.InitializeView();
        var searchController = new UISearchController(searchView)
        {
            SearchResultsUpdater = searchView,
            ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover,
            ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
        };
        searchController.SearchBar.Placeholder = "Search events";
        searchController.Active = true;
        searchController.AutomaticallyShowsSearchResultsController = true;


        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
        {
            searchController.ObscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true;
            //searchController.SearchBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
            searchController.SearchBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.SecondarySystemBackgroundColor;
            searchController.SearchBar.TintColor = ColorPalette.TintColor;
            searchController.SearchBar.Translucent = false;
        }
        else
        {
            searchController.DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true;
            searchController.SearchBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default;
            searchController.SearchBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(200, 200, 200);
            searchController.SearchBar.Translucent = false;
            searchController.SearchBar.TintColor = ColorPalette.TintColor;
        }

        
        searchController.PopoverPresentationController.BarButtonItem = this._searchButton;

        this.PresentViewController(searchController, true, null);
    }
```

So the above code works correctly in iPhone, it displays the following UI:

[image]

But on the iPad it displays pretty much blank, not sure why the Search textbox isn't even visible.

[image]

Comment: And you are sure the size of your controls is correct and fits within the frame you have given the popover?

Comment: Well that’s the thing. The code behaves differently on the iPad completely. I don’t supply the search bar or anything the only thing that’s supplied is a view to ui search controller which is a plain uitableview.

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: @WenxuLi Zip file of a sample project is here: https://smokeballus-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/winston_pang_smokeball_com/EetikjVKw39FgwNRwxvGiqQB6lbH9KCAHHn7s-poJCN1Qw?e=mYWgVq So as you can see the issue is that when you run this on iPhone, the Pop over shows you the Search Box, when you run it on the iPad simulator, it shows the popup, but there's no Search Box, is this something that's intended?

Answer (score 0):

According to my search, it may not be supported on ipad. I tried to add `searchController.PopoverPresentationController.BarButtonItem = this._searchButton;` to the controller, and the search box was successfully displayed on the ipad. You can try this method, you can also try to use UINavigationController.